# Linux; On the fly access control for flows

Tags: linux, linux-networking, access-control-list

In a Linux host environment: Is there a way to check once per new flow (source ip, source port, dest ip, dest port)-tuple, or similar, if a flow is allowed to be established. The deny/allow should come from an external process, e.g., a (bash) script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel `netfilter` firewall implementation has `NFQUEUE` target, which allows passing of packets to userspace for deciding further actions for the traffic flow.

One of the actions is called marking, which marks the flow with a value. This value can then be matched in `netfilter` rules to allow further flow packets to go directly through without going to userspace.

Comment: Not sure if the marking would really help with the "once" per flow requirement, but this is obviously the way to do this.

Comment: Marking will help, when the IPTables which allows marked packets through is before the NFQUEUE rule in the chain.